# Cups daemon is now running under "cups" user+group. Printers stop working

Tags: permissions, printing, cups

The cups package in Arch Linux had a recent update with the following changes:

> Cups daemon is now running under "cups" user+group. Please make sure
>   to enable the new user+group change in /etc/cups/cups-files.conf or
>   merge changes from /etc/cups/cups-files.conf.default. After a service
>   restart make sure /etc/cups and all files within are owned by cups
>   group - run "chgrp -R cups /etc/cups".

I performed the following steps:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart org.cups.cupsd.service 
chgrp -R cups /etc/cups
reboot
```

After that, our Brother QL-1060N printer will not print, but there are no error messages.

Next I tried:

```
gpasswd -a myser cups
```

Still no luck. Is adding the user to the cups group a bad idea?

(So that my user can manager printers, my user is a member of the "sys" group and that group is a member of SystemGroup in /etc/cups/cups-files.conf)

What should I try next?

Comment: Did you rebuild the AUR package?

Comment: @jasonwryan - rebuilding the AUR package resolved it. It doesn't seem obvious to me that this would be required. How did you know this would resolve it? Thanks

Comment: @jasonwryan Is adding my user to the cups group necessary? Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: You are always required to rebuild AUR packages against the new repository packages. No, adding your user to the group is not necessary.

Comment: @jasonwryan I have not seen that mentioned on the Arch wiki. I probably missed it, but it doesn't seem widely known...

Comment: Well, it is self-evident if you think about it. The AUR is unsupported, therefore when official packages are updated, it is up to you, not pacman, to update those packages against the new libraries.